# Embeded syntax highlighting and code completion for a special tag

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

We all know that PhpStorm automatically detect codes inside a `<script>` tag.

But in my case, my tag name is something else, it is: `<system:javascript:block>`

PhpStorm does not understand how the codes inside this tag should be displayed, so there is no syntax highlighting and code completion.

How can I tell the app to consider codes inside such tags as JavaScripts?

Comment: just show that..

Comment: edited, SO censored some part of my post, it is fixed now.

Comment: Try creating custom Language Injection rule: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/language-injections.html?search=language%20inj 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Language+Injections+%28mix-ins%29+in+PhpStorm . I'm just not sure if it will work with such `system:javascript:block` name (because of `:` symbols)